# Do unequal time intervals for waves parameter in gee analysis matter? (geeglm in R)

Tags: r, generalized-estimating-equations, geepack

Consider a standard study of n patients (given as `id` variable), several time points of measurement (given as `measurement.order`), and some variables `x1, x2`, that are supposed to correlate with `y`. The gee model in R is the following:

```
library(geepack)
geeglm(y ~ x1 + x2, id = id, waves = measurement.order, corstr = "independence")
```

In my real-world retrospective analysis, **time points for measurement are not equal** for all subjects: Measuremnts may occur at any time, i.e. the **interval between measurement** 1, 2 and 3 may be *3 and 4 months for patient 1*, but *9 and 2 months for patient 2*. In fact, not even the **number of measuremnts per patient** and the time between first and last measuremnt is equal.

**My question: does that matter?** I.e. can I use `measurement.order = 1:3` for pat. 1 and 2 (both have 3 measurements with unequal intervals), `1:4` for pat. 3 who has 4 measurements, and so on? Do I need to specify the intervals (how??)? Or do I need to e.g. order all time points from all patients, and then have missing values for a patient with a longer interval? (In fact, this would create more missing than actual values, since time intervals are unequal). Am I correct to assume that this matters more with `corstr = "ar1"` than `"independence"`?